# Acceder a funciones anidadas JavaScript desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código JS e intento acceder a las funciones `start()` y `stop()` desde un `div` con los eventos `onmouseover=""` y `onmouseout=""`:

```js
NewsScroller = function(id, speed) {

  this.start = function() {
    _timer = window.setInterval(self.doScroll, this.scrollSpeed);
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    if (_timer) window.clearInterval(_timer);
  };
};

var scroll = new NewsScroller('marquesina', 10);
```

```html
<div id="marquesina" onmouseover="scroll.stop();" onmouseout="scroll.start();">
  Soy una Marquesina
</div>
```

Pero al ejecutar me dice que `start` y `stop` no son funciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué otra manera puedo mandar llamar las funciones anidadas para que funcione?

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es que se esté llamando mal las funciones `start` y `stop`, el problema es que [`scroll` es el nombre de un método de `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-ES/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll). Y dentro del contexto de `onmouseover` y `onmouseout`, `scroll` se va a referir al `scroll` de la ventana y no a tu variable `scroll`.

Una solución rápida sería renombrar tu variable, por ejemplo a `miScroll`:

```js
NewsScroller = function(id, speed) {
  
  this.start = function() {
    console.log("START");
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    console.log("STOP");
  };
  
};

var miScroll = new NewsScroller('marquesina', 10);
```

```html
<div id="marquesina" onmouseover="miScroll.stop()" onmouseout="miScroll.start()">
  Soy una Marquesina
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda no tenia el conocimiento de que dentro del contexto de los eventos lo tomara como método de windows.